# JavaScript-form validation

Tags: javascript, jsp, validation

I am doing some form validation in JSP, on click on submit button "validate_access()" function is not called or not working. Sometimes this function displays a alret box and then stop doing any thing . Please tell what is wrong with this piece of code.Here is a piece of code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Data management system</title>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

            function validate_access()
        {
              var a = document.forms["myForm1"]["MISDN"].value;
              var b = document.forms["myForm1"]["Issue"].value;
              var c = document.forms["myForm1"]["SR"].value;
              var d = document.forms["myForm1"]["date"].value;
              var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
              var alpha= /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
              var Datee= /^\d{1, 2}\/\d{1, 2}\/\d{4}$/;
            if(document.myform1.MISDN.value=="" && document.myform1.Issue.value=="" && document.myform1.SR.value=="" && document.myform1.date.value=="")
            {
              alert("Manadotry fields should not left blank");
              document.myform1.MISDN.focus();
              document.myform1.Issue.focus();
              document.myform1.SR.focus();
              document.myform1.date.focus();
              return false;
            }
            else if(!a.value.match(numbers))
            {
                 alert('Please input numeric characters only');  
                 document.myform1.MISDN.focus();
                 return false;
            }
            else if(!(b.value.match(numbers) && b.value.match(alpha)))   
            {  
                  alert('Please input numeric and alphabets only');  
                  document.myform1.Issue.focus();
                  return false; 
            }  
            else if(!c.value.match(numbers))  
            {
                  alert('Please input numeric characters only');  
                  document.myform1.SR.focus();
                  return false;

            }
            else if(!d.value.match(Datee))
            {
                  alert('Please input correct date');  
                  document.myform1.date.focus();
                  return false;
            }
            else
                return true;


        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="main">
     <div class="header"></div>
     <div class="continer">
         <div class="myform1" style="height:200px; width:300px; float:left;">
            <h2>1344 Access</h2>
            <form name="myform1" action="access.jsp" method="get" onsubmit="return validate_access()">
                <br/>MSISDN:<input type="text" name="MISDN" maxlength="11">
                <br/>Issue:<input type="text" name="Issue" maxlength="13">
                <br/>SR:<input type="text" name="SR">
                <br/>Date:<input type="text" name="date" value="dd/mm/yy">
                <br/><input type="submit" value="Submit">
                <br/><input type="reset" name="Reset">

            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="myform2" style="float:left;height:200px; width:300px;">
            <h2>O.C.S</h2>
            <form name="myform2" action="ocs.jsp" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_ocs()">
                <br/>MSISDN:<input type="text" name="MISDN" maxlength="11">
                <br/>SR:<input type="text" name="SR">
                <br/>REASON:<input type="text" name="reason">
                <br/><input type="submit" value="Submit">
                <br/><input type="reset" name="Reset">
            </form>
        </div>    
     </div>
 </div>



</body>
```

Comment: you can check it out with your browser console . press **F12**

Comment: @SanKrish sorry i am not much familiar with debugging on browsers !

Comment: Better don't use JSP anymore. Use JSF 2 (with Facelets) and use the Java Bean Validation API, as described in this tutorial: http://oxygen.informatik.tu-cottbus.de/webeng/JavaJpaJsfApp/validation-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems in your javascript are:

- the first if condition check is wrong you mean `||` in place of `&&`.
- then next when you call `match` method on empty string a error probably raise like:

  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`
- you calling `.focus()` continuously that doesn't making any sense, call once with a condition check.

Comment: Please also tell @Rembo how to implement check for both numeric data and alphabets in javascript!

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in this line:var a = document.forms["myForm1"]["MISDN"].value;
Look at your source code, your form name is "myform1" not "myForm1".

Comment: javascript is case sensitive, but in your javascript code,sometimes you use 'myFomr1' sometimes you use 'myform1'.in your html source code you use 'myform1',you must check your source code.You can add some alert("...") to debug your code,which is the most easiest way to debug program.The better way is use the console of brower to debug.if you use chrome, you can press F12 to debug.

Comment: Please also tell @feng how to implement check for both numeric data and alphabets in javascript!

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript is case sensitive**. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax

in your js:

```
document.forms["myForm1"]
```

but in your form(html) it is:

```
<form name="myform1"
```

Try this:

```
function validate_access()
{
    var a = document.forms["myForm1"]["MISDN"].value;
    var b = document.forms["myForm1"]["Issue"].value;
    var c = document.forms["myForm1"]["SR"].value;
    var d = document.forms["myForm1"]["date"].value;

    var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
    var alpha= /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    var Datee= /^\d{1, 2}\/\d{1, 2}\/\d{4}$/;           

    if(a == "" && b == "" && c == "" && d == "")
    {  //as you have default value for d (date field), this condition will never match;
       //either you can remove default value or provide different logic
        alert("Manadotry fields should not left blank");
        document.myForm1.MISDN.focus();
        document.myForm1.Issue.focus();
        document.myForm1.SR.focus();
        document.myForm1.date.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(a == "" && !a.match(numbers))
    {
        alert('Please input numeric characters only');  
        document.myForm1.MISDN.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(!(b.match(numbers) && b.match(alpha)))   
    {  
        alert('Please input numeric and alphabets only');  
        document.myForm1.Issue.focus();
        return false; 
    }  
    else if(!c.match(numbers))  
    {
        alert('Please input numeric characters only');  
        document.myForm1.SR.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(!d.match(Datee))
    {
        alert('Please input correct date');  
        document.myForm1.date.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;    
}
```

Your mistakes:

(i) form name spelling mistake (caseSensitive)

(ii) you used HTMLElement.value.value to check (in if conditions)

```
For example:
   var a = document.forms["myForm1"]["MISDN"].value;    
   a.value.match(numbers);   // it simply means  HTMLElement.value.value (which will never work)
```